# Set Focus on a Textbox - MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I set focus on "Amount" textbox on page load for the following Razor code in MVC3?

```
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)
                </div>                            
            </th>
             <td>
                 <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
                 </div>                          
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could provide an additional class to the containing div:

```
<div class="editor-field focus">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
</div>
```

and then you could use a jQuery class selector:

```
$(function() {
    $('.focus :input').focus();
});
```

This being said you seem to have multiple `Amount` texboxes in a table and obviously only one can have the focus at a time. So assuming you want this to be the first, you could do this:

```
$('.focus :input:first').focus();
```

Comment: Perfect!  It worked.  It is a simple and great solution. Thank you so much and you saved me lot of time.  The Stackoverflow users are great!  They helped me many times and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Where does the jQuery class selector go?  In a script section above the form?

Comment: @JenniferS did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: @JenniferS any script section or js file referenced on the required page. It's just a simple jQuery selection call (find the first element with the class "focus" and is the first input field). Obviously you'll want to tweak it to match your specific requirements.

Comment: I put it in a master page.. all is OK.

Comment: It is ok to put it in a master page, but it will not work with partial views. It is better to create a script file, place reference in BundleConfig.cs and then use a '@Script.Render("~/bundles/<ScriptFile>")' in the master page and any partial views you might have.

Answer (score 50):

with a html 5 compliant browser you set the autofocus

```
<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" />
```

if you need IE support you need to do it with javascript

```
 <input type="text" id=-"mytextbox"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('mytextbox').focus();</script>
```

in razor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount,new{@autofocus="autofocus"})
```

Comment: Supported in all major browser(latest), Internet Explorer 10(but bot IE9), Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: this is a better answer these days, although the question didn't specify anything about html5

Comment: This was the cleanest simplest way for MVC5 with the HTML helpers, worked brilliantly.

Comment: This is the real answer.

Answer (score 37):

Open the /Views/Shared/Site.Master file and enter the following after the jquery script include this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[type=text]").first().focus();
    });
</script>
```

This will set the focus to first textbox on every form in the app without writing any additional code!

Comment: My first input on form was a number so I changed it to    $("input[type=number]").first().focus(); and it worked. However, it won't work now for the first input being text. This is data type in the EF table column, not the input type. Any ideas how to check type first?

Comment: You don't need [type=...] however this helps to make sure you are selecting the correct <input> tags in your application.  You might be able to get away with $("input").first().focus();

Answer (score 5):

The trick is that these input elements always have an `id` attribute, which you can get as a string with `Html.IdFor`. So you can focus the one you want with Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("@Html.IdFor(model => model.Amount)").focus();
```

Or, if you prefer jQuery:

```
$("#" + "@Html.IdFor(model => model.Amount)").focus();
```

Comment: I tried your solution with no luck. I tried Darin Dimitrov's solution and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using MVC4/Razor, and don't happen to have a Site.Master file in my project, However, I do have an _Layout.cshtml file that is applied to every page (Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml), so I added this to an existing script in that file, as follows. This works well for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            // ajaxSetup code here...
            }
        });
        // Set the focus to the first textbox on every form in the app
        $("input[type=text]").first().focus();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this.  Now that I'm onto MVC4/Razor, this saves me a lot!

Comment: Glad you found it to be helpful!

Comment: Doesn't work if input is bound to number column in table. Then you have to use type=number.